# How To get dpix and dpiy value for Windows 8 app (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

The Device Information Class which gives these properties is not supported in Windows 8. Is there any alternative to find these values for a windows 8 device.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 8, there is no great option. Consider requiring Windows 8.1.

You can use [resolutionScale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.resolutionscale) which was available in Windows 8 base.

```
var resolutionScale = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.resolutionScale;
```

For Windows 8.1, The best API I beleive you're looking for is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.rawdpix.aspx). To retrieve the `X` value:

```
var rawDpiX = displayInformation.rawDpiX;
```

Make sure you look at the documentation for the warnings about occasions when this value may return `0`.

Comment: Sorry if i offended you. Actually my aim is to find the physical display size of device in inches. Using dpix and dpiy we can find that out. Is there any we can find out using only DisplayProperties class.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the only display related values I'm aware of for Windows 8.  8.1 has the better support unfortunately.